# Inner join with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get Max bid and that username but result is coming in wrong way

Here is my two tables

Product

```
id | name | username 
 1 |  A   |   deen 
 2    B   |   ann
```

Bid

```
id | c_bid | username 
 1 |   10  |   ann
 1 |   12  |   ann
 1 |   13  |   ann
 2 |   10  |   ann
 1 |   15  |   Hel
 1 |   16  |   Hel
```

SQL

```
  SELECT name, bid.username AS username, MAX(bid.c_bid) AS c_bid FROM product INNER JOIN bid
    ON  gems.id= bidding.id  WHERE bid.id = '1'
```

Result

```
  name | c_bid | username 
    A  |   16  |   ann
```

Why is this result coming on this sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an aggregate function you need to include a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT name, 
  bid.username AS username, 
  MAX(bid.c_bid) AS c_bid 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN bid
  ON  product.id= bid.id  
WHERE bid.id = '1' 
GROUP BY name, bid.username
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f40d/4)

You are getting strange results because MySQL uses an [Extension to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) that allows you to use an aggregate function without using a GROUP BY but this could cause your result to be incorrect.

The GROUP BY makes it so you will return the `max(bid)` for each item that you are grouping by, in your case it is `name` and `username.

If you want to return only one `max(bid)` for each product id, then you could use:

```
SELECT name, 
  bid.username AS username,
  bid.c_bid
FROM product 
INNER JOIN bid
  ON  product.id= bid.id  
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT max(c_bid) c_bid, id
  FROM bid
  GROUP BY id
) b
  on bid.id = b.id
  and bid.c_bid = b.c_bid
WHERE bid.id = '1'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f40d/7)

Comment: I need only Maximum bid and its username, when i try this its coming two quays

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT name, bid.username AS username, MAX(bid.c_bid) AS c_bid FROM product INNER JOIN bid
    ON  gems.id= bidding.id  WHERE bid.id = '1' GROUP BY bid.username;
```

Comment: i think this would work SELECT name, bid.username AS username, MAX(bid.c_bid) AS c_bid FROM product INNER JOIN bid
    ON  gems.id= bidding.id  WHERE bid.id = '1' GROUP BY name,bid.username;

Comment: yep, i missed the name.

Comment: when i user group by its coming 10 ann and 16 hel both :(

Comment: I thought that was what you needed. Can you edit and add an expected result?

Comment: i need only one max(c_bid)

Comment: maybe you can try to get the max bid and the username first on a sub-query, and then join it with the product table and get the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.username,
    MAX(b.c_bid) AS max_c_bid
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN bid b ON (p.username = b.username)
GROUP BY p.username;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    pr.name,
    mb.c_bid,
    pr.username
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY c_bid DESC), ',', 1) AS id,
        MAX(c_bid) AS c_bid
    FROM bid
    GROUP BY id
) AS mb
JOIN product AS pr ON(pr.id = mb.id)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a6c9/2